# PHP require() dando erro 500

Tags: php, require

Estou com um sistema desenvolvido há pouco tempo em PHP7 no Windows, e, resolvi migrar para o Debian9. De momento tudo funciona, porém o autoload (psr-4) localizado em vendor está com problemas ao requirir as classes, retornando error 500 no browser.

Executei `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` e ele retorna `PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Src/Core/Router.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/project/vendor/autoload.php on line 16`.

Já tentei utilizar caminho absoluto, assim como relativo, porém nenhum funciona.

### Testes

> Quando executo is_writable ou is_readable ele também retorna o erro.
>
> Criei um index.php na root (/var/www/html/) e incluí o arquivo index.html dentro do projeto e funcionou; por isso descartei permissões, que são: folder (755) / files (644).
>
> No mesmo arquivo index.php verifiquei se o Router.class.php existe e ele retorna true. Porém se o fizer no autoload retorna false.

Sempre trabalhei com Debian e nunca havia ocorrido esse problema.

### Referências

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569941/php-require-causing-http-500-error?rq=1

https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/PHP/HTTP-500-INTERNAL-SERVER-ERROR-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erro 500 é generíco, ou seja não adianta procurar especificamente sobre ele, você tem que ler a mensagem de erro do LOG. O erro em

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Src/Core/Router.class.php'

Isto quer dizer que o arquivo não existe, os motivos possíveis são:

**Case-sensitive:**

Você esta usando um servidor Linux ou Mac OSX, então:

- A pasta `./Src` na verdade esta em minusculo e deveria ser `./src`
- Ou o arquivo `Router.class.php` deveria ser `router.class.php` no teu autoload

Em sistemas Windows você ele é case-insensitive, por isto provavelmente funciona, mas se fizer isto no nome do arquivo `Foo.php` e no require `foo.php` em um Debian/Fedora/Mac/etc não vai funcionar.

**Nome do arquivo esta errado:**

Pode então ser um erro de digitação, tanto no nome do arquivo quanto no caminho (ou seja não esta na pasta), independente de ser absoluto ou não.

A unica maneira de ter certeza é se você informar se você informar o minimo como:

- isto (`Router.class.php`) é um framework de terceiros instalado via composer?
- Você quem criou o `Router.class.php` e adicionou manualmente?
- Você configurou como o `composer.json`? (poste ele na pergunta)

Comment: Na verdade usei o "erro 500" como referência, fica mais fácil caso alguém pesquise pelo mesmo problemas; sobre o case-senstive, no autoload eu trato isso.

Comment: @TutoXTutoriais erro 500 é generico, é um erro interno de falha do software de interpretação ou dependencia, só expliquei isto para especificar melhor como buscar os problemas, voltando ao assunto que importa, veja a edição da resposta, tente dar detalhes para confirmarmos, eu creio que é alguma coisa boba, um erro de digitação provavelmente.

Comment: Todas as classes foram criadas por mim, não utilizo lib de terceiros, até porque o projeto não é tão grande. Irei atualizar a pergunta com mais detalhes.

Comment: @TutoXTutoriais como eu já disse, sem olhar o composer.json e a estrutura de pastas eu não tenho como nem ter ideia do que você fez amigo, afinal de contas só você tem acesso ao seu composer.json e pastas, se você informar esses detalhes importantes ai sim eu vou conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira: quando definir o autoload, o composer tava como Src/Core/ e ao requirir ele estava utilizando o strtolower. No final foi apenas erro de digitação dos paths. Valeu.

Comment: @TutoXTutoriais que bom que deu certo, case-sensitive temos que tomar cuidado ;)